# Unable to send image from frontend to cloudinary or the backend in general

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image, cloudinary

I am trying to send an image from the frontend to cloudinary to be used as profile picture in my app using the code below:

```
import { StyledInput, StyledLabel} from '../FormInputs/styles'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { StyledButton } from '../Button/styles'
import axios from 'axios'

export function FileUploader() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null)
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
  const [showImage, setShowImage] = useState()

  function handleChange(e) {
    readFile(e.target.files[0])
    setFile(e.target.files[0])
    console.log(e.target.files[0])
  }

  function readFile(file) {
    const reader = new FileReader()

    reader.readAsDataURL(file)

    reader.onload = e => setImage(e.target.result)
    reader.onerror = e => console.log(reader.error)

  }

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

    const data = new FormData()
    if(file) {
      data.append('file', file[0], file[0].name)
    }

  const response = await axios({
    method: 'PUT',
    base: 'http://localhost:8000',
    url: '/clients/clientprofile',
    data,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  })

  console.log(response)
  // setShowImage(response.image)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <StyledLabel htmlFor="file">Elegir foto de perfil</StyledLabel>
        <StyledInput
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          name="file"
          id="file"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <StyledButton type="submit">Enviar Foto</StyledButton>
      </form>
      {image && <img src={image} alt="Profile Picture Preview" />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I select the image it works fine, however, when I click the "Upload Image" button, it errors out with the below error:

[image: 1]

I am defining file by using the `setFile()`, however, when I `console.log(file)` it returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

Since the `console.log()` is async, it was logging null because it was executing before the `state` had time to change, and the issue with the undefined was due to an error of the config in the backend.